# pagination for custom post type archive page

Tags: wordpress, loops, pagination

I'm trying to add pagination to following code inside archive-CustomPostType.php page but it doesn't show pagination or it shows empty page.
My code:

```
   <?php get_header(); ?> 
 <h2 class="ptm pbm mbl text-right red-bg"><span>سریال</span></h2>

<div class="container">

 <?php 
            $terms =  get_queried_object();

          $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

               $posts = get_posts(array(

                 'post_type' => 'series',
                 'posts_per_page' => 20,
                 'paged' =>$paged,
                  'category'   => $terms->term_id,

                 'meta_query' => array(
                     array(
                     'key' => 'is_season',
                     'compare' => '==',
                     'value' => '0'
                   )
                 )

               ));
               if( $posts ): ?>
            <ul>
               <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
                  setup_postdata( $post )

                  ?>


              <!--HTML goes here-->



               <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
             <div class="pagination">
        <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?> 
      </div>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif; 
                  ?>

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm using page navi for pagination but I don't think it's the problem because I tried with normal wordpress pagination but didn't help.

I think the issue is coming from `get_queried_object` and I don't know how to handle this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does $posts return any data?

Comment: Below code is working for you?

Comment: @andrew-schultz yes, it does. it works correctly but as soon as i add pagination I see empty pages

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This Code.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <h2 class="ptm pbm mbl text-right red-bg"><span>سریال</span></h2>

    <div class="container">

        <?php 
            $terms =  get_queried_object();

          $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

               $posts = get_posts(array(

                 'post_type' => 'series',
                 'posts_per_page' => 20,
                 'paged' =>$paged,
                  'category'   => $terms->term_id,

                 'meta_query' => array(
                     array(
                     'key' => 'is_season',
                     'compare' => '==',
                     'value' => '0'
                   )
                 )

               ));
               if( $posts ): ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
                  setup_postdata( $post )

                  ?>


                    <!--HTML goes here-->



                    <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <div class="pagination">
                <?php
        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'mid_size'  => 2,
            'prev_text' => 'Previous',
            'next_text' => 'Next',
        ) );
    ?>
            </div>

            <?php else : ?>
                <p>
                    <?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?>
                </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                    ?>

    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Modifying query post type in functions.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts' ,'wpse222471_query_post_type_portofolio', 1, 1 );
function wpse222471_query_post_type_portofolio( $query )
{
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'customposttype' ) && $query->is_main_query() )
    {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 ); //set query arg ( key, value )
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code but the pagination still displays empty pages. For example I have 40 posts, it shows 10 pages...